# Title and URL of articles in site based in Wikimedia automatically changed to lowercase

Tags: mediawiki

I can't speak English very well. So I ask for your understanding.

I have a one site based in Wikimedia.

And.. I have a problem.
When I write articles, page automatically modified to uppercase (first alphabet).

Like this:
iPhone => IPhone

Please click the link.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Lcq.png)

I want to my site work like Wiktionary. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia requires that all pages start with an uppercase letter. That’s why the search results and the URL are “IPhone”. This behaviour can be overwritten by using the *lowercase title* template. Simply write `{{lowercase title}}` somewhere near the beginning of your page. Cf. [Template: Lowercase Title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Lowercase_title)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know about {{lowercase title}} too. But... ListView is important for me. (like third image). I wish it well have the possibility.

Comment: @Kwon I’m sorry. If that doesn’t fit your needs, I’m at my wits’ end. I suppose that manipulating the search results is out of your control and would have to be implemented by administrators. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: I thank for your help. I'll keep trying solve this problem.)